# Visualize ContentDialog at full width in the UWP Framework from C# code

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, markdown

I have an UWP application where I dynamically show a ContentDialog when certain buttons are tapped.
The ContentDialog will contain **markdown text** that is dynamically loaded from a configuration file based on which button was clicked. The markdown text contains also references to images (just for information these images' width is 2480 pixels)

```
private async void ImageHelp_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
try
{

    MarkdownTextBlock markdownTextBlock = new MarkdownTextBlock();
    
    // BASED ON SENDER (button) IT WILL BE DIFFERENT
    markdownTextBlock.Text = ReadMarkDownTextFromConfig(sender); 

    markdownTextBlock.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);


    ScrollViewer sv = new ScrollViewer();
    sv.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Auto;
    sv.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
    sv.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
    sv.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Enabled;               
    sv.Content = markdownTextBlock;

    ContentDialog notifyDialog = new ContentDialog
    {
        Content = sv,
        CloseButtonText = "Ok"                    
    };

    await notifyDialog.ShowAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex) { MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog(ex.Message, "Error"); _ = msg.ShowAsync(); }
}
```

What I want is that the ContentDialog is visualized at "full width", I have tried setting the width of the ContentDialog but that didn't helped much.
I have tried this :

```
 notifyDialog.MaxWidth = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
```

And this:

```
 notifyDialog.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
```

Even if I tried these the actual width of the ContentDialog is half of the Window's width.
Even if I set it to a very large number it remains the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @Adam Mcmahon's solution about using `Popup`, an alternative way is to change the default MaxWidth of the `ContentDialog`. The default `ContentDialog` MaxWidth is 584 that was setting in the generic.xaml file. To override it, you need to add it in the App.xaml like this:

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <x:Double x:Key="ContentDialogMaxWidth">5000</x:Double>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a `Popup` rather than `ContentDialog` then the following should do what you need.

As far as I'm aware - You cannot make a `ContentDialog` any larger than it's default Max Width. You can create a custom control but this is a much simpler solution if you can work with a `Popup`

XAML

```
    <Popup VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid x:Name="PopupGrid"></Grid>
    </Popup>
```

C#

```
    PopupGrid.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
    PopupGrid.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
```